# Control level of audio ducking in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiokit

I am trying to control the level of ducking audio from other applications like Spotify or music while my own app produces audio to control and make a relative audio between the two.

I’ve looked through the documentation in AVAudioSession and all I can see is that there is a ducking ability with no parameters to set a value. I know that in ios7 you could use AudioSession set property to set the ducking value.

Is there any solution to doing this in iOS 10?